# DNS not working on WS2003, but nslookup works fine

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, nslookup

I have a virtual machine with Windows Server 2003 (SP2). The DNS resolution seems to be broken, but the nslookup command works fine. Well, I guess that means that the DNS resolution works fine, but I get this response when I ping any domain:

Ping request could not find host *FQDN*. Please check the name and try again.

That brings all kinds of problems. The email server cannot send messages because it doesn't get the IP addresses for the domain names, etc.

The DNS servers work fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

ipconfig /all result

```
Configuración IP de Windows

   Nombre del host . . . . . . . : S15350948
   Sufijo DNS principal  . . . . :
   Tipo de nodo. . . . . . . . . : de igual a igual
   Enrutamiento habilitado . . . : No
   Proxy WINS habilitado . . . . : No

Adaptador Ethernet venet0:

   Sufijo conexión específica DNS:
   Descripción . . . . . . . . . : Parallels Virtual Network Adapter
   Dirección física. . . . . . . : 00-FF-7E-1C-68-10
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . : No
   Dirección IP. . . . . . . . . : xx.xx.xx.xx
   Máscara de subred . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Puerta de enlace predet.. . . : 192.168.109.113
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . : 208.67.222.222
                                   208.67.220.220
                                   127.0.0.1
                                   8.8.8.8
                                   8.8.4.4
                                   87.106.2.251
                                   195.20.224.234
                                   195.20.224.99
```

I tried OpenDNS and Google's Public DNS. I've already removed/reordered the DNS servers.

```
>ping google.com
Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again

>nslookup google.com
Servidor:  dns2.schlund.de
Address:  195.20.224.99

Respuesta no autoritativa:
Nombre:  google.com
Addresses:  209.85.148.103, 209.85.148.147, 209.85.148.105, 209.85.148.106
          209.85.148.104, 209.85.148.99
```

Comment: What does ipconfig /all say ?

Comment: How exactly do you run the ping and nslookup commands ? A sample would be nice. (Combined with the ipconfig /all output as adaptr asked.)

Comment: @Tonny ping google.com
nslookup google.com

Comment: The only difference is that `ping` is using local dns cache, while `nslookup` performs direct ns query. Use `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear cache before trying again.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know when a program tries to connect somewhere it passes the domain name to the OS functions and OS uses its resolver library to do the lookup. On the other hand nslookup is doing lookups on its own.

I've seen something like that on my Win XP and it was probably caused by some new program, virtus or malware, because reverting to a week old Point of recovery solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is that the correct Default gateway? What is your networking mode in Parallels?

Comment: Just had the same "issue" today -- ping not "resolving". Turned out default gateway was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. They were caused by a virus. Try running disk scan from Kaspersky or NOD32 live CD (you can download and run them for free).

Comment: Will give it a try.